LTspice syntax error no such function
I created a subckt model. It is working fine with ngspice. In LTspice 24.0.12, however, I am getting

This is my source code:
... blah
.func myfunc(g,V) { I0*exp(-g/g0)*sinh(V/V0) }
... blah
BMain top_electrode_x bottom_electrode I = { myfunc(V(g)*capacitance_of_integrating_capacitor, V(top_electrode)-V(bottom_electrode)) }
... blah

According to the documentation this should work.

Please show the rest of the circuit, you reference node g, what is it? Where are the parameters coming from. I got this function to work on my computer.

Please provide a minimized netlist that still illustrates the problem (works in ngspice and doesn't work in LTspice.) The ... blah ... blah doesn't really cut it, as I don't trust your own analysis where you believe that therefore all we need to know is shown in that single .func line. You are likely wrong about that conclusion. But regardless I'd like to see a minimum example.
